# Capture multiple values from Vue Formulate select input

Tags: vue.js, vue-formulate

I'm stuck on VueFormulate, specifically I'd like to populate an array from a `<FormulateInput type="select" name="products">` component. That idea should be that every time you select an option that option should go into the `products` array of the model bound to `<FormulateForm v-model="user">` but instead `products` just become a primitive integer instead of an array.

Let me show you some code from the SFC of the form itself

```html
<template>
  <FormulateForm v-model="user" name="example" @submit="performSomething">

   <!-- Other fields working fine !-->

   <FormulateInput
        type="select"
        name="products"
        :label="$t('form.inputs.products.label')"
        :placeholder="$t('form.inputs.products.placeholder')"
        :options="products.map(p => ({ label: p.name, value: p.id }))"
      />

  </Formulateform>
</template>
```

```js
props: {
   products: Array
}

// User model bound to Formulateform

data: () => ({
    user: {
      name: "",
      description: "",
      products: [], // This should be populated by the select box
    },
  }),
```

The expected behaviour should be that `user.products` gets filled with IDs from the select on every input, but instead it just replace the array with the ID of the **first** select.  Of course I'm missing something but I don't get what, documentation does mention that every `FormulateInput` has an `@input` event but I'm not able to use it because the even itself is fired only once then I only get `FormulateForm` events

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was my fault, how surprising. More info on the solution here: https://github.com/wearebraid/vue-formulate/issues/318